# Change web images to black and white

Tags: php, gd

I'm using a API to get some photos from a famous web. And I want to take that pictures and change them to black&white, to re-display in my web but with the colors changed.
Is there any possibility to do it without having to store the images on the disk?

THanks.
Sorry for my English.

Comment: What does "a famous web" mean? Do you have the necessary rights and permissions to republish these photos?

Comment: I need to take a users photos throught Facebook API. But he's a person with vision problems, so he needs photos in black&white...but in another web.

Comment: @user550252: I think you mean "website", not "web".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng('yourfile.png');

if($im && imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE ))
{
    echo 'Image brightness changed.';

    imagepng($im, 'sean.png');
    imagedestroy($im);
}
else
{
    echo 'Image brightness change failed.';
}
?>
```

Comment: wouldn't `IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE` make more sense? (Assuming "black & white" is not meant literally as a 1-bit-depth-image)

Comment: Cassy - would be - this is just example - but fixed

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's possible, but don't do it, it'll almost certainly be a breach of the terms of use of that site.

Comment: If possible, please tell me how.

Comment: This should have been a comment.